# Combination Edge list conditional upon common id

Tags: r, combinations, network-analysis

I want to create an edgelist conditional upon id -

```
  combine = data.frame( id=  c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2) , pid = c("john","tom","dick","tom","harry","dick","sick"))

desired output:
person1 person2  id
john     tom      1
john     dick     1
tom      dick     1
tom     harry     2
tom     dick      2
..n so on
```

what would be correpsonding code in R ?

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to modify your input data frame a little bit to simplify the solution:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                 person = c("john","tom","dick","tom","harry","dick","sick"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

The next step would be to merge the data frame with itself:

```
dfe <- merge(x = df, y = df, by = "id", 
             suffixes = c("1", "2"))
```

The only thing that remains is to remove duplicate edges. This can be done by assuming for example that edges are sorted alphabetically:

```
dfe <- dfe[dfe$person1 < dfe$person2,]
```

On another note, I advise you to read up on the 'igraph'-package. Much of what you are trying to accomplish and more is available there.

Comment: Much more compact than the effort I was working on that involved `split`-ting on "id" and then using `t(combn(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

i did it like this

```
   library(tidyverse)
    combine = tibble( id=  c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2) , pid = c("john","tom","dick","tom","harry","dick","sick"))

    combo = function(x){

    combine %>% filter(id==x) %$% t(combn(pid,2)) %>% as_data_frame()%>% add_column(id=x)}
    map_df(unique(combine$id),combo) 
     V1    V2       id
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 john  tom      1.
2 john  dick     1.
3 tom   dick     1.
4 tom   harry    2.
5 tom   dick     2.
6 tom   sick     2.
7 harry dick     2.
8 harry sick     2.
9 dick  sick     2.
```